# how to merge repeat dataset value to single dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

Am using foreach loop that contain some code to retraive data from database. first time it returns some rows from database.In second looping it returns some rows so and so. My question is may i merge the looping rows to single dataset?. 
please help me to merge that row values to single dataset....

Comment: You've heard of [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx)?

Comment: Are the datasets the same structure in terms of the data? or totaly different?

Comment: Dataset fromat is same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim Schmelter mentioned there is also the Merge() method on datasets.  This will allow you to different types of merges, including updates which will stop you having duplicate rows if you have the same row in each dataset.  This maybe better than using a for loop to add the rows from one to the other depending on the type of data you have.

you can read more on this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is provided I understood you correctly ...

```
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Then just add the DataTable to a DataSet of your choice.